# Keep getting blank image when save UIView...how to save UIView & subviews onto camera roll?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, camera, uiimage

I have a `UIView canvas` which I would like to save a screen shot of it (and it's subviews) on a camera roll when I press the `UIBarButton shareBarButton`. However, when I press the `shareBarButton` the image that appears in the camera roll is completely blank black screen.

Any help on why this is happening would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to suggestions on other (perhaps better) ways to save `UIViews` onto the camera roll.

This is the method attached to `shareBarButton`

```
func share(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let masterpiece = canvas.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
    let image = convertViewToImage(masterpiece)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

This is the helper function which convert the `UIView canvas` into a UIImage

```
func convertViewToImage(masterpiece: UIView) -> UIImage{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(masterpiece.bounds.size, masterpiece.opaque, UIScreen().scale)
    masterpiece.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860300/2303865

Comment: Your question title doesn't really describe your problem. Your code shows that you know how to save it to the camera roll you should change it and mention the blank image instead

Comment: Try [UIScreen.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScreen/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:). And if that doesn't work, use [ASScreenRecorder](https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder) and save a single frame.

Comment: It's [UIView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(_:afterScreenUpdates:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) (instead of UIScreen.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

to take screenshot:

```
func captureView(view: UIView) -> UIImage {
        var size: CGSize = self.imageViewObject.image.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        self.imageViewObject.image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        self.imageOverLayObject.image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```