# Taking and sharing Screenshot using Swift in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I just made a simple game using Swift in SpriteKit. At the end scene, it shows Score, Share and Restart button.

The function for sharing screenshot of the end scene is still pending. I found a very simple solution here, https://www.frispgames.com/sharing-a-screenshot-on-ios-using-swift-and-sprite-kit/

I'm not a pro, therefore all my attempts so far to implement this solution is in vain.

I'm trying to call `shareScore()` function (as written in that solution) when the player taps `shareButton()` but it isn't working.

Here's my code for the EndScene

```
var restartBtn = SKSpriteNode()
var shareBtn = SKSpriteNode()
var scoreLbl = SKLabelNode()
var score = Int()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    scene!.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    self.view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    scoreLabel()

    shareBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Share")
    shareBtn.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height / 3)
    shareBtn.setScale(0.0005)
    self.addChild(shareBtn)

    restartBtn = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Restart")
    restartBtn.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width / 2, self.frame.height / 4)
    restartBtn.setScale(0.0005)

    self.addChild(restartBtn)
}


func scoreLabel() {

    let scoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    score = scoreDefault.valueForKey("score") as! NSInteger

    scoreLbl.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    scoreLbl.fontSize = 40
    scoreLbl.setScale(0.001)
    scoreLbl.text = "Score: \(score)"

    self.addChild(scoreLbl)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if restartBtn.containsPoint(location) {

            let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
            let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
            let skView = self.view! as SKView
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            gameScene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            skView.presentScene(gameScene!, transition: transition)

        } else if shareBtn.containsPoint(location) {

            // Function for sharing screenshot should be called here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I just included the my code as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't show how you are using `shareScore()` function so I have created one simple example for you from the tutorial you given and it's working fine and below is complete sample code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Spaceship")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        sprite.xScale = 0.5
        sprite.yScale = 0.5
        sprite.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        self.addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

             if sprite.containsPoint(location) {

                let postText: String = "Check out my score! Can you beat it?"
                let postImage: UIImage = getScreenshot(scene!)
                let activityItems = [postText, postImage]
                let activityController = UIActivityViewController(
                    activityItems: activityItems,
                    applicationActivities: nil
                )

                let controller: UIViewController = scene!.view!.window!.rootViewController!

                controller.presentViewController(
                    activityController,
                    animated: true,
                    completion: nil
                )
            }
        }

    }

    func getScreenshot(scene: SKScene) -> UIImage {
        let snapshotView = scene.view!.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
        let bounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, 0)

        snapshotView.drawViewHierarchyInRect(bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let screenshotImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return screenshotImage;
    }
}
```

And when you click on Spaceship image you will get result like:

[image]

Now you can easily share it.

[Sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=16045184065501125158) code for more Info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I made a separate `ShareScore.swift` file for that function and tried to call it in `if shareBtn.containsPoint(location)`

Comment: Now I implemented your solution and and yes its showing this sharing popup, but I just noticed another problem with it. It doesn't take screenshot, rather its saving a white image with nothing in it.

Comment: Check sample project. I have tested that and it's working fine.

Comment: I test that on actual device and still having the same problem. The screenshot is totally white with nothing on it

Comment: I'm able to get it working by tweaking the solution with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860300. Should I add that piece of code in your answer?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I added that piece of code in `getScreenshot` function. And its working good  : )

Comment: Hi again. I was testing this solution on iPad Simulator, and found that it breaks the app when I hit `Share` button :/

Comment: I had to add something extra to make it work... mixed two different answers into one... but still, im getting the "Please log in" if i want to share it on facebook. Do you guys know why?

Comment: What is the idea behind creating a snapshot view (`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`) and then calling `drawViewHierarchyInRect` on that view? Why not to call `drawViewHierarchyInRect` directly on `scene.view!`?