# How to resize UIView with subviews to fit a PDF?

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiview, transform

Could anyone describe how to resize a UIView that contains subviews right before saving to a PDF so it all fits on the page?

I have a UIView that has a bunch of labels in it. The labels depend on user input, so the parent view can get really tall if the user inputs a lot.

What are the options to resize the UIView so that it always fits the page, even if it has to shrink to scale?

I've tried:

```
let maxHeight: CGFloat = 792
if myView.frame.height > maxHeight {       //myView is the parent view
let scale = maxHeight / myView.frame.height
myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale)
}
```

I'm guessing what resulted was the frame shrunk, but not the contents of the view. The subviews stayed the same size, and even if the frame does cut off the contents, it isn't clipping them off (I don't want it to, I'm just noting what the code is doing).

Ideally the result would be a shrunken frame that otherwise looks exactly the same. Thanks for all help!

-Sean

Comment: You could take a snapshot and then shrink then transform the snapshot (this can be done at retina resolution)

Comment: Ah great idea. Is it possible to take a snapshot of a view that goes beyond the screen?

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe a snapshot can only be taken of what is on the screen.

Comment: Also, try setting `autoresizesSubviews` on your `myView` to true.

Comment: @SeanC.Li you can render any view. It doesn't need to be the same size of your screen http://stackoverflow.com/a/29860300/2303865

Comment: You may also want to set `autoresizingMask` equal to `[ .flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin,.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]` for your subviews in addition to my most recent comment. And @LeoDabus, I meant that it must be within the bounds of the screen.

Comment: Ok tried it out:

The sizes of the views change, but not to scale when printing to PDF. They're kind of all over the place and I can't make sense of it yet (if I can, I'll update this post more).

I think they're not lining up the same. So say I have three labels with unique background colors next to each other. Their origin points correspond with their widths, so they're next to each other and touching. I believe when they scale down, they're not staying next to each other, but perhaps shrinking to their respective centers?

I'm testing more and will keep updating. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Here are my steps:

1- Create the parent UIView, and added subviews with `subview.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin]`

2- Used `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale)` on the parent UIView, like how I mentioned at the beginning

3- Render to PDF