# How to convert a View (Not ddisplayed) to JPEG image?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code to convert a view to image. But i want my image to be in jpeg format.What chnages do i need to make in this code to get my image as JPEG format. I am not showing my view in device.

```
extension UIView{
    func createTransparentImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        renderFormat.opaque = false
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.layer.isOpaque = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: renderFormat)
        return renderer.image{
            (context) in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear... Do you want to create a `UIImage` to use elsewhere in your app? Or do you want to save the content of the `UIView` as a jpeg format file? And the code you included appears to simply create a completely transparent image?

Comment: I want to save the content of the uiview as a jpeg format

Comment: Actually i need jpeg format for some processing. Yes i can convert that image again into jpeg format. But i want to reduce cost here by creating jpeg format directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/29860300/2303865

Comment: There is no way to create a jpeg directly. You need to draw your view hierarchy into a new UIImage context then you can get its jpeg data representation. Note that jpeg has no alpha channel. If you need transparency you need a PNG data representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with your extension you get back a `UIImage` if you want you can save it as `JPEG` or `PNG`, by converting it to `Data` or `NSData` in Objective C:

```
let viewSnapshot = view.createTransparentImage()
//save as JPEG
if let data = viewSnapshot.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) {
    //variable data has the JPEG image with quality of 80%
}
//save as PNG 
if let data = viewSnapshot.pngData() {
    //variable data has the PNG data of the snapshot
}
```

If you wanted to save this image you can just do the following inside of the `if let data`

```
let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
if let documentsDirectory = paths.first {
    let fileName = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myImage.jpg")
    try? data.write(to: fileName)   
}
```

Given that you do not need `UIImage` but only JPEG `data` just do a slight modification on your extension as follows:

```
extension UIView{
    func createImageData(quality: CGFloat = 0.8) -> Data {
        let renderFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        renderFormat.opaque = false
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.layer.isOpaque = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: renderFormat)
        return renderer.jpegData(withCompressionQuality: quality, actions: { context in
            layer.render(in: context.cgContext)
        })
    }
}
```

Notice the final line was changed to:

```
return renderer.jpegData(withCompressionQuality: quality, actions: { context in
```

Thus to use this you can simply do:

```
let viewSnapshotData = view.createImageData(quality: 0.9)
```

As per LeoDabus you can use the following extension to get snapshot of a `UIView` with alpha transparency if it is needed:

```
extension UIView {
    var snapshot: UIImage {
        isOpaque = false
        backgroundColor = .clear
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
        format.opaque = false
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: format).image { _ in 
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't i create jpeg image directly?

Comment: Okay thank you. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I modified your extension so you dont do the UIImage to Data dance, but only get the Data in JPEG format as you want

Comment: Changed the naming of the last extension method, it already has the layer.isOpaque = true so there will be no transparency in the original method he posted :)

Comment: He specifically needs JPEG data, I answered that you can get both JPEG and PNG if needed but he needed JPEG that is why I wrote the last extension to use the JPEGData

Comment: But he needs JPEG data to do the processing, he does not want PNG, I do agree with everything you are saying, was just trying to help with what his requirements were :)

Answer (score 1):

```
extension UIView{
func captureViewAsImage() -> UIImage? {
    var screenshotImage :UIImage?
    let layer = self.layer
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return screenshotImage
  }
}
```

and use this function as

```
 let img = view.captureViewAsImage()
```

Comment: But my full image is being black.

Comment: did you debugged you view to  see whether it has some component or not may be your view background is clear and it not have any property or you selecting wrong view?

Comment: The code i provided is working completely fine but my code is producing png format and i want jpeg format.

Comment: convert image in data and than convert data in to jpeg format

Comment: Thank you #nack22